# What does the object[foo] term mean?

Tags: javascript

I'm confused what the `object[foo]` term is referring to.  Any hints?  I know that `bar['unique_prop']` and `bar.unique_prop` refers to `2`

```
    var foo = {unique_prop: 1};
    var bar = {unique_prop: 2};
    var object = {};
    object[foo] = 'value';
    alert(object[bar]);
```

[code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4gJf/)

Comment: Sorry for the dupe vote, I didn't fully understand the question and it cannot be undone.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario it can be undone if the question is closed.. it can be reopened. :)

Comment: lol, no worries I wouldn't even know it was you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
var foo = 'abc';
object[foo]
```

is equivalent to:

```
object.abc
```

However this:

```
var foo = {unique_prop: 1};
object[foo] = 'value';
```

Doesn't have much sense (object property names cannot be object literals). JS engine will use `foo.toString()` (returning e.g. `"[object Object]"`), so in fact you are doing this:

```
var foo = {unique_prop: 1};
object["[object Object]"] = 'value';
```

which is clearly a bug or a misunderstanding. This behaviour is explained in [Member Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript):

> Property names must be strings. This means that **non-string objects cannot be used as keys in the object**. Any **non-string object, including a number, is typecasted into a string via the toString method**.

You can however use:

```
object[foo.unique_prop] = 'value';
```

which is equivalent to:

```
object[1] = 'value';
```

Comment: I was confused since this is the first time I saw an object literal in brackets, this is an example from the mozilla site where I got the code piece from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators

Comment: @LedZeppelin: the document you are referencing explains this behaviour, I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

It is the same as `object.whatever_x_is` where `x` is `foo.toString()` which will be the same as `bar.toString()` since (unless overridden) calling `toString` on a generic object will generate a generic "is an object" string such as `"[object Object]"`

Answer (score 1):

```
object[foo] = 'value';
```

attempts to use an object as a member name, this causes a `.toString()` call so;

`'value'` is assigned to `object["[object Object]"]`, when you attempt to read `alert(object[bar]);` the same `toString()` occurs as `bar` is also an object, so you reference  `object["[object Object]"]` once again and get back `'value`'.