# Javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Im am working with some code from another developer and came across something I have not seen before. The basic functionality of the code is to look for a piece of data in an object within an object. The object format is `theObj {key:Object, key:Object,...}`, the data being searched for is stored in 2 variables `inkey`,`lookfor`.

```
$.each(theObj, function(m,n){
    if(typeof(n['data'][inkey]) != "undefined" && n['data'][inkey] !== null) {
        if(n['data'][inkey][lookfor] == 1){..}
    }
});
```

What does the `['data']` do?

Comment: It's the same thing as `n.data`.

Comment: It is the key in the object. Meaning n['data'] means get `value of key(propery name) data in object n`.

Comment: It's called **bracket notation**. It access the property `data` or the object `n`. You already know this from arrays: `arr[0]` accesses the first element of the array, the property `0` of the array `arr`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9095779/218196.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n['data']` is the same as `n.data` but sometime it's useful to use brackets like when you need to use a variable like `n['data'][inkey]`.

Btw you or him should use `n.data.hasOwnProperty(inkey)` instead of `typeof(n['data'][inkey]) != "undefined"`

You could write it like that :

```
$.each(theObj, function(m,n){
    if(n.data.hasOwnProperty(inkey) && n.data[inkey] !== null) {
        if(n.data[inkey][lookfor] == 1){..}
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

It is looking for a property `data` in the object `n` - `n['data']` is the same as `n.data`

Answer (score 1):

`data` is the property name or key in the object. So `n['data']` would return the property value for the property name `data` in object `n`.

And what you have is an Object not an Array.

Array contains list of elements with integer based index, where else Object contains list of elements with key based index.