# Understanding Javascript Object Code Snippet

Tags: javascript

I came across [this code snippet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) on Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) and I am racking my brain in trying to figure out why the result would indeed be 'value'

```js
var foo = {unique_prop: 1}, bar = {unique_prop: 2}, object = {};
object[foo] = 'value';
console.log(object[bar]);
```

I would be grateful if someone would be so kind as to enlighten me!

Comment: I think it's because it toStringifies object indexers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the object\[foo\] term mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095779/what-does-the-objectfoo-term-mean)

Comment: The example you linked to gives you your answer: _This also outputs "value", since both foo and bar are converted to the same string. In the SpiderMonkey JavaScript engine, this string would be "['object Object']"._

Answer (score 3):

```
object[foo] = 'value';
```

You can only have strings as identifiers and hence when the above runs, JavaScript internally calls `ToString` method, which represents `"[object Object]"`. That's how objects are represented.

Now when you do `object[bar]`, `bar.toString()` is also `"[object Object]"`, and since `'value'` is stored with `"[object Object]"` as key, it gets returned.

Comment: This has helped a lot ..Cheers Steve

Answer (score 1):

If you have a quick look in your console, you will see this is because `foo` is being coerced into a `string` (since all keys in Javascript are strings**), which defaults to `[object object]`. The string `[object object]` is *the same* for every object, so `foo` appears to be `bar`, but in essence it is not. Check out the below output:

```js
var foo = {unique_prop: 1}, bar = {unique_prop: 2}, object = {};
object[foo] = 'value';

var output = document.getElementById('p')
for(thing in object){
  output.textContent += thing + " = " + object[thing];
}
```

```html
<p id='p'></p>
```

** I think that ES6 has a way of setting a computed key using `{[func]: value}` syntax, but I have not looked into this very deeply yet, so excuse me for the possible incorrectness.

Comment: The same answer than @mic4ael but with an explained code. mic4ael has 3 downvotes....

Comment: It's worth noting that _all object keys are strings_ in JavaScript.

Comment: Per your update, the computed key still results in a string, it's just that they can be generated dynamically in object literals (rather than using bracket notation on an already created object.)

Comment: @Mathletics Does that mean they are computed when the object is generated and never again? (If so, then yes, all keys are strings and I will amend :) )

Comment: That's my understanding, yes. They are computed when the literal is generated.

Comment: @Mathletics I will leave my side-comment in the answer as it's not an unsafe extra and it does not say it is one way or the other, therefor mostly harmless but good to know. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can see what's going on here with 3 mini experiments:

1. What is the result of toString() called on each of the objects you create?

   `foo.toString()`, `bar.toString()` and `object.toString()` will output:

   ```
   [object Object]
   ```
2. What is the result of `object[{}]`?

   it is also `"value"`, because the key that the runtime used to store your value is literally `[object Object]`
3. Let's change the behaviour of toString and see what happens.

   ```
   Object.prototype.toString = function(){
     return this.unique_prop;
   };

   // Re run the code

   object[foo] = "value";

   console.log(object[bar]);  // Returns undefined

   // Value was stored under the key "1"
   console.log(object[1]);  // Returns "value"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Because the key in this object is a string representation of the foo and bar objects, like
`Object {[object Object]: "value"}`.

Comment: @Mathletics `object[bar]` it's an access to a object property as an array

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude are you joking, no it isn't. Don't confuse bracket notation with arrays; they are not the same thing.

Comment: It's an **access** to an **object property** as an array.

Comment: __There are no arrays here.__ If you have an object `var obj = {a: 'a'}`, you can access `obj.a === obj['a']`. At no point is there any array.

Comment: I just noticed that I wrote `array` instead of `object`. My imission.

Comment: mic4ael sorry your post is getting blown up; I am only trying to correct @MarcosPérezGude who is very confused

Comment: no, I'm not confused, but my poor english is avoiding to me to explain what I want to say. Yes: I know that is not an array, but you can access to an object property as you access to an array key. True? I said this. I repeat: `It's an access to an object property as an array`. It's hard to explain in english because I don't talk english fine. Sorry

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude in any language, what you're saying is incorrect. Yes, you can access properties of objects and indexes in an array using bracket notation, but the sentence _It's an access to an object property as an array_ doesn't make sense; it has nothing __at all__ to do with arrays.

Comment: Ok, we are misunderstanding. I know that you said. I try to say the same, but we are in an infinite loop LOL!

Answer (score 0):

As explained above, setting the object property results with an object stringifys the key

```
> console.log(foo.toString())
[Log] [object Object]
```

so object[foo] is equivalent to

```
object["[object Object]"] = 'value';
```

However if you actually wanted them to be different you could do something like this:

```
> console.log(JSON.stringify(foo))
[Log] {"unique_prop":1}

> object[JSON.stringify(foo)] = 'donkey'
> console.log(object)
[Log] {[object Object]: "value", {"unique_prop":1}: "donkey"}

> console.log(object[JSON.stringify(bar)])
[Log] undefined
```